# Why when I load Woocommerce products via AJAX I lose functionality

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a products filter on a custom post type template using AJAX. I am able to populate products but for example when a variable product loads I lose the functionality to update price based on which variation of the product is selected, as well as the ability to add to cart. How can I accomplish a product filter that will not lose the core Woocommerce functionality?

AJAX CODE:

```
$(document).on('click','.wc_categories_tab_container' , function(){
var value = $(this).find('.wc_categories_tab').attr('parent_term_id');
var name = 'cabinet_categories';
var url = window.location.href;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: wc_add_to_cart.ajaxurl,
    data:{ action:'cabinet_product', 'term':value, 'taxonomy':name },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.wc_products_archive').html('LOADING PRODUCTS PLEASE WAIT');
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        $('.wc_products_archive').html(data);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
    }

});

});
```

PHP FUNCTION:

```
function cabinet_product(){

if (isset($_POST['taxonomy'])) {
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-blog-header.php");
?>
<ul class="products">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $_POST['taxonomy'],
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['term']
                ),
            ),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.single_add_to_cart_button').addClass('product_type_variable');
});
</script>
<?php

}
    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_cabinet_product', 'cabinet_product' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cabinet_product', 'cabinet_product' );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just edited my question with the code I am using so that you can better understand what I am talking about. I don't think the click function is the problem though.